# Converting HashMap<String, List<String>> to XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to marshall an object into XML, this object extends `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. However it's unclear to me as to why the output does not contain the data entered in this object. The method used to marshall this object into XML can be found near the end of the question.

#### Example 1 (actual situation)

Data structure:

```
@XmlRootElement
class WhatIWant extends HashMap<String, List<String>> {

}
```

Which is filled using:

```
WhatIWant what = new WhatIWant();
what.put("theKey", Arrays.asList("value1", "value2"));
```

The resulting output is as follows, the data entered is nowhere to be found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<whatIWant/>
```

---

#### Example 2 (situation which generates expected result)

Something like this does work and is what I expected the output of the first example to look similar to.

Data structure:

```
@XmlRootElement
class MyHashmap {
    public HashMap<String, MyList> map = new HashMap<>();
}

class MyList {
    public List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Filled using:

```
MyHashmap requirement = new MyHashmap();
MyList t = new MyList();
t.list = Arrays.asList("value1", "value2");
requirement.map.put("theKey", t);
```

The resulting output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myHashmap>
    <map>
        <entry>
            <key>theKey</key>
            <value>
                <list>value1</list>
                <list>value2</list>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </map>
</myHashmap>
```

---

#### Object to XML method

The method which I used to turn the objects into XML:

```
public static String getObjectAsXML(Object obj) {
    try {
        // Create marshaller
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Marshall the object
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(obj, sw);

        return sw.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

### The question

1. Why does `Example 1` not generate output similar to the one in `Example 2`? Why does not not generate anything at all?
2. What should be done to get XML output for a structure like `Example 1`? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be because of the following:
The elements to be marshalled/unmarshalled must be public, or have the XMLElement annotation.

In your first example, the root class has no public elements, while the second does. You could try to add (to the first example) a public getter returning the map entries (and add appropriate @XmlAccessorType to the WhatIWant class) and see if it gives the expected results

Comment: You might be onto something, changing `List` to `ArrayList` (JAXB has issues with a normal `List`) and adding a getter and setter which set and get `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` atleast prints the key part of the `HashMap` (`<key>theKey</key>`) but the `ArrayList<String>` part is printed as `<value/>`. Any more ideas?

Comment: Probably because the `ArrayList<String>` part of `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` still has no public or XMLElement annotation, however the only fix I see for this is creating a custom class which extends `ArrayList<String>` aswell and adding getters and setters to that, which would not be ideal and looks a lot like my `Example 2`